# Buttons work not properly in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The problem is when I click button generated in ngRepeat, its behavior is unpredictable. It can respond on first click or on fifth. The most stable behavior is reaction on double click.

I have completely reproduced the problem piece of my project in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/4wFEcH01d8y69cCRQgrl).

The issue checked in Chrome, Firefox and Edge with identical result.

My guess is that problem caused by the way Angular generates scopes... but I am very new to Angular and wasn't successful in fighting this problem for a whole week. So please, could anybody help? :)

```
<table class="table attendance" ng-repeat="task in groupAttendance| groupBy: 'taskId'">
    <caption class="header-primary">
      <a>Task {{($index + 1)}} | {{task[0].title}}</a>
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header-secondary">
        <th ng-repeat="date in task| unique: 'classDate'">
          {{getDayOfWeek(date.classDate)}}
          <br> {{formatClassDate(date.classDate)}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="student in task | groupBy: 'studentId' | toArray: true | orderBy: orderByName">
        <td ng-repeat="attendance in student track by attendance.attendanceId">
          <md-button class="attendance-button" ng-click="showEditAttendanceDialog($event, attendance)" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
            <md-icon ng-class="{'green-700': present, 'red-700': absent, 'yellow-700': absentWithReason}">
              {{attendanceStatus(this)}}
            </md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this row:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="student in task | groupBy: 'studentId' | toArray: true | orderBy: orderByName">
```

`toArray: true/false` causes to problem

The solution is to add `track by $index` like:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="student in task | 
                      groupBy: 'studentId' | 
                      toArray: true |
                      orderBy: orderByName track by $index" >
```

Working <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R92bN6C1r7AAIa5GWwaL?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Regards to `@Mike` answer `... I believe the code is too slow.` The index tracking should improve app. performance since you add indexing and not angular (that too expensive)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! You've made me happy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Along with Maxim's answer, I believe the code is too slow.
When you bind to a function instead of a scope variable, this function can be executed more often than you would think. Sometimes it is better to pre format the data, creating a new property on the object once, then binding to that.

I added logging statements to attendanceStatus, and when I click a button it seems like that function is called a thousand times.

Comment: I changed attendanceStatus function binding to one way one and that solved the problem of calling it thousand times. There's no need in two-way binding in that place. Despite the fact this wasn't cause of problem, thank you for that optimization as well!